# Segmentation fault 11 behavior on different machines

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I ran a depth first search program in C++ for a very large graph. The dfs is written in a recursive way. I got segmentation fault 11 on my laptop, but can't find any bugs. I then ran it on a linux server, it runs fine.

I am curious what the difference is. I suspected the stack size because the program is recursive, but as I checked with: `ulimit -a`, both computers have stack size of 8192 kB. I can't find other limits that might cause this problem. Do you know why I got the difference? Thank you!

Comment: You can get the difference because your program can have a bug that just happens to appear to work on one platform and not another. The solution is to fix the bug. The tools Gregor suggests are well worth learning and using. I'll speculate and say it's probably an invalid memory access such as an off-by-one error, use-after-free, using uninitialized memory, etc.

Comment: When the same code acts differently then there's probably some undefined behavior around

Comment: How large is large? Since the stack size probably grows logarithmically with N (assuming your graph is sparsely-connected, and fairly balanced), you ought to be able to handle a *very* large graph with 8MB of stack.

Comment: In addition to what @GregorMcGregor mentioned, try using a static analyzer like cppcheck or clang's static analyzer to find "obvious" mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

A "segmentation fault" is just one of possible outcomes of what's formally defined as "undefined behavior".

The existence of a segmentation fault can be generally concluded to be conclusive evidence that, in some manner, the application engages in "undefined behavior".

And the reason that it is called "undefined behavior" is exactly that: the behavior of the application is not defined. The actual behavior may depend on the processor, architecture, the time of day, the phase of the moon, or who won the World Series. Sometimes the application will crash with a segmentation fault. Other times it might run to the end, apparently producing the expected results, or perhaps results that are subtly wrong, in an undetectable behavior. You can't expect any particular behavior from the program, because it is undefined.

And this is what "undefined behavior" means. A better known synonym for "undefined behavior" is a "bug".